# Why is there a rapid ejection phase followed by a slow ejection phase in isotonic contraction, why isnt this a steady rate?

Tags: cardiology

Trying to work our how the cardiac cycle works by gaining a deep understanding, would appreciate any explanations which go into such depth and what variations we may see if this was a pathological case with every different wave etc. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.